# AutoHotKey dynamic hotkeys

Tags: python, dynamic, autohotkey, shortcut, hotkeys

I tried to write a ahk script which allows me to bind the currently opened window to a hotkey. 
The way it works is that if you press <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> + any character, the ProcessPath of the current window gets saved.

Now, using <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + the choosen character, i either switch to this window if its already opened (Activate) or run the .exe file for this process.

To delete the hotkey i use <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> + respective key.

All hotkeys get saved in an .ini file so the settings don't get lost.

It all works fine..... but 
**the thing is: I had to copy the code for every key (i wrote a python script to copy it for me).**
**Is there a way to set dynamic hotkeys in ahk?**

Here is my code:

```
iniFile := "winshortcut.ini"
```

Runs a certain process or switches to the window if already running. The loop works around some delays that might occur.

```
RunOrActivate(key, Target)
{
    SplitPath, Target, TargetNameOnly, , TargetEXE
    Process, Exist, %TargetNameOnly%

    If (ErrorLevel > 0){
            WinActivate, ahk_pid %ErrorLevel%
    } else {
        if (Target != "ERROR") {
            Run, %Target%

            if (TargetEXE != "exe"){
                WinGetTitle, x, A
                if (x != TargetNameOnly){
                    Loop, 5 {
                        Sleep, 100
                        Run, %Target%
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            TrayTip AltGr+%key%, No binding, 2
        }
    }   
}
```

This line reads the path for a key from the ini file. I had to copy it for every single key:

```
IniRead, PATH_w, %iniFile%, savedKeys, w
IniRead, PATH_r, %iniFile%, savedKeys, r
...
```

This block handles the hotkeys for saving, deleting or changing the process for a **single key** (<kbd>w</kbd>). This is copied and changed 23 times:

```
; ############## w ##############

<^>!w::
if (GetKeyState(",")){

    if (PATH_w != "ERROR") {
            SplitPath, PATH_w, TITLE_w_old
    }

    WinGet PATH_w, ProcessPath, A

    SplitPath, PATH_w, TITLE_w

    if (TITLE_w == "Explorer.EXE"){
        WinGetTitle, TITLE_w, A
    for w in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        if (TITLE_w = w.Document.Folder.Self.Name) {
            PATH_w := % w.Document.Folder.Self.Path
        }
    }

    IniWrite, %PATH_w%, %iniFile%, savedKeys, w

    if (TITLE_w_old) {
            if (TITLE_w_old != TITLE_w){
                    TrayTip Changing binding for AltGr+W, From %TITLE_w_old% to %TITLE_w%
            } else {
                    TrayTip Binding for AltGr+W, %TITLE_w%
            }
    } else{
            TrayTip New binding for AltGr+W, %TITLE_w%
    }
 } else if (GetKeyState(".")){
    PATH_w := "ERROR"
    TITLE_w_old := ""
    IniDelete, %iniFile%, savedKeys, w
    TrayTip AltGr+W, Binding deleted

} else {    
    RunOrActivate("W", PATH_w)

}
return
```

Is there a way in ahk to pack hotkeys into a single function?

Here is the whole thing including the python code i wrapped around:

[bitbucket.org: autohotkey-winshortcut](https://bitbucket.org/wankoelias/autohotkey-winshortcut/src)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly are you trying to achieve. You can define multiple triggers by stacking the hotkey triggers and you can refer to the last hotkey, no matter which is pressed, using [`A_ThisHotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey).

Comment: You can use the [HOTKEY](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command to create, modify, enable, or disable a hotkey while the script is running

Comment: Also, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

See [AppFactory](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=38651), this has a built-in Dynamic Hotkeys system, complete with "Press key to bind" prompts, options to select wild, block etc, and also saves everything to an INI file for you